# Break sentences in XML using PHP

Tags: php, xml, split

I am new to PHP and i have an xml file and i want to extract the sentences in the xml file to an array using PHP, to break down the sentences to having 3 words each time. The sentences will be divided into parts.
The XML below is from a XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<document>
    <content>
        <segment>
            <sentence>
                <word>Hi</word>
                <word>there</word>
                <word>people</word>
                <word>I</word>
                <word>want</word>
                <word>to</word>
                <word>introduce</word>
                <word>you</word>
                <word>to</word>
                <word>my</word>
                <word>world</word>
            </sentence>
            <sentence>
                <word>Hi</word>
                <word>there</word>
                <word>people</word>
                <word>I</word>
                <word>want</word>
                <word>to</word>
                <word>introduce</word>
                <word>you</word>
                <word>to</word>
                <word>my</word>
                <word>world</word>
            </sentence>
        </segment>
    </content>
</document>
```

The output will be:

```
Hi there people
I want to 
introduce you to
my world
Hi there people
I want to 
introduce you to
my world
```

I have created a function to process the xml trannscript.

```
function loadTranscript($xml) {
    $getfile = file_get_contents($xml);
    $arr = simplexml_load_string($getfile); 
    foreach ($arr->content->segment->sentence as $sent) {
        $count = str_word_count($sent,1);
        $a=array_chunk($count,3);
        foreach ($a as $a){
            echo implode(' ',$a);
            echo PHP_EOL;   
        }
    }
}
```

But was unable to produce the output. Is `$sent` considered an array? I want to break the sentences at XML level.

Comment: `$getfile = file_get_contents($transcript);` < that's not actually doing anything afaict (apart from generating an unset variable warning presumably)?

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at XPath - it's quite a nice tidy way to navigate XML documents : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp and can be used with both SimpleXML and DOMDocument it turns out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why everyone is so scared of SimpleXML, and I think it's definitely the right tool for this job.

`$sent` is not an array, but an object representing the `<sentence>` element and all its children; it has some array-like properties, but not ones that `array_chunk` can work with.

You can actually use `array_chunk`, but you need to do three things to make your current code work:

- cast `$sent` from object to array with `(array)$sent` (which will give an array of *all* children of the `<sentence>` node) or `(array)$sent->word` (which will limit it to those called `<word>`, in case there was a mixture)
- pass in that array to `array_chunk`, not `$count` (which you don't need)
- don't use the same variable twice with conflicting meanings (`foreach( $a as $a )`)

So:

```
$chunks = array_chunk((array)$sent->word, 3);
foreach ($chunks as $a_chunk) {
    echo implode(' ', $a_chunk);
    echo PHP_EOL;   
}
```

Alternatively, you can do without `array_chunk` easily enough by just displaying a newline every third word:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ( $words as $word ) {
    $counter++;
    echo $word;
    if ( $counter % 3 == 0 ) {
         echo PHP_EOL;
    } else {
         echo ' ';
    }
}
```

Then all you need to do is nest that loop inside your existing one:

```
foreach ($arr->content->segment->sentence as $sent) {
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ( $sent->word as $word ) {
        $counter++;
        echo $word;
        if ( $counter % 3 == 0 ) {
             echo PHP_EOL;
        } else {
             echo ' ';
        }
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Up to you which you think is cleaner, but it's good to understand both so you can adapt them to future needs.

Comment: Not scared of it - just don't like it... I have a solution with DOMDocument and XPath - which is actually very similar to this ... but I'm trying not to post it because the question specified SimpleXML, so you can have a +1 instead ;)

Comment: Just like @ CD001, i'm not scared about it. It's just...ugly to me, but of course a good option. +1

Comment: @James Scared, dislike, ugly, whatever; I still don't get it. I want to loop over the `<word>`s in this `<sentence>`, so I write `foreach ( $sentence->word as $word )`; what could be simpler? Why would I want to manually create a bunch of different helper objects and manage the relationship between them? *shrug* Each to their own, I guess.

Comment: This object-like syntax is really simple, I agree. However, I prefer DomDocument 'cause I think that i have a better control over my XML, knowing exactly what is an tag, attribute and etc... As you said, matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

Is `$xml` a string or a file path? I'm considering that is a string for this answer.

Use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and make it happens

```
function loadTranscript($xml) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($xml);
    $words = $doc->getElementsByTagName('word');
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if ($i >= 3) {
            echo "\n";//it works on console. For browsers you should use echo "<br>";
            $i = 0;
        }
        echo $word->nodeValue.' ';
        $i++;
    }
}
```

I used a extra `$i` flag to avoid the foreach inside another foreach, but you can adapt the code to your needs.

As suggested by @CD001 in the comments, following is a new version that consider more than one tag `<sentence>`.

```
function loadTranscript($xml) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($xml);
    $sentences = $doc->getElementsByTagName('sentence');
    foreach($sentences as $sentence) {
      $words = $sentence->getElementsByTagName('word');
      $i = 0;
      foreach ($words as $word) {
          if ($i >= 3) {
              echo "\n";
              $i = 0;
          }
          echo $word->nodeValue.' ';
          $i++;
      }
      echo "\n";
    }
}
```

To read the XML from a file, replace the `$doc->loadXML($xml);` by `$doc->load('file/path/string.xml');`

Comment: That's OK until you get 2 sentences - then, in this case, the start of the second sentence gets appended to the end of the first - but I agree that DOMDocument is the way to go... I hate working with SimpleXML for some reason.

Comment: @CD001 Are you sure that doesn't work with more than 2 sentences? See my test code [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a409a071e78583c53f6dd9d58cdc2d268d5178d1). I think thats work fine, but maybe I not understood your comment. Yep, DomDocument is much better than SimpleXML to me too.

Comment: it is a file path.

Comment: Technically that's lots of words in a single sentence... looking at the code it implies there could be multiple `<sentence>` blocks. That being the case you'd want blocks of words broken up into those sentence blocks. I modified your sandbox code to demonstrate: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/71ed304a88bf86c8ccdec3fe1994371c4fd23bad

Comment: @CD001 I got your point now. indeed, i considered just one `<sentence>` tag, 'cause the OP's question does not guided me to think about the possibility of more than one tag. You're are right, but it can be solved with an outer foreach. I will edit my answer to match this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose, W3C-conformant language (sibling to XPath) designed to transform XML documents. XSLT can transfrom to text formats. With this approach, no `foreach` loop or `if` logic is needed. PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with its built-in [php-xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) extension which may need to be enabled in .ini file. And the beauty of XSLT is that it *is* a well-formed XML file and can be parsed like source XML from file or embedded string.

Specifically, the XSLT runs the *Identity Transform* to copy document as is without nodes and then for each `<word>` node, template checks if the current position is a multiple of three to add a line break. And then adds a line break after the last `<word>`. Notice too at top `<xsl:output>` method is *text*.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>    
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="word">    
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
    <xsl:if test="(position() mod 3) = 0">
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**PHP**

```
// LOAD XML AND XSL
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->load('Input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl); 

// RUN TRANSFORMATION
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// ECHO STRING OUTPUT
echo $newXML;

# Hi there people
# I want to
# introduce you to
# my world
# Hi there people
# I want to
# introduce you to
# my world
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm sure this is great if you know XSLT, but telling somebody "hey, I see you're struggling with PHP, try learning this notoriously unreadable specialist language on top of it" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Forgive me, just because you do not like XSLT is not reason for downvote. XSLT is a special-purpose, declarative language much like SQL. It is a complementary language not a replacement. You would hate to retrieve database records without SQL.

Comment: I have answered XSLT in general-purpose language like Python, R, VBA, Java, etc. boards with many thanks, always advising transformations to be run in a language designed for it.

Comment: It *is* a correct answer to solve the problem though (rather than solving the solution) - so a downvote seems uncalled for...

Comment: It just feels like overkill for this use case, is all. The mistakes in the question suggest to me that this is someone without much experience of PHP, and XSLT is a whole new set of concepts to learn. If you learn to do this using a couple of loops and if statements, that would then work equally well given JSON, or YAML, or a set of database records. (As for "the beauty of XSLT is that it is a well-formed XML file", my personal opinion is the opposite: like XML Schema, it's expressing things in XML that would be much simpler with a dedicated syntax.)

Comment: I agree with @IMSoP that is overkill for a simple task, but maybe the OP feels comfortable with the XSLT syntax making it an excellent answer, so +1.